# How can I stop people from messing up this Word document with text boxes?

Tags: microsoft-word

**What I have:**

I have a document that requires three things:

1. Description of Non-Compliance
2. Disposition
3. Remedial Action Taken.

… as well as Several signatures and dates. The document is set up currently with linked text boxes.

**For example:**

When I start typing in the "Description of Non-Compliance" text box, when it reaches the end of the text box, it automatically continues on Page 2 which is "Non compliance Supplemental" page.

The same goes for "Disposition". It goes to page three which is the "Disposition Supplemental" page, and the same for "Remedial" action: It goes to page 4 which is the "Remedial Action Supplemental" page.

**The problem is:**

When I issue this document, they often mess up the document because they don't use Word that often and are not familiar with it.  I would like to protect the document and use the "fill in forms" mode. So whoever uses the document in "fill in forms" mode can't type in the text boxes.

Comment: how about an image instead of a textbox?

Answer (score 1):

I think Word is the wrong tool for this job.

Consider using a PDF file that contains a form.  You can even get a PDF form to lock itself and email itself once completed by the user, providing a level of non-repudiation.